# Run C++ loop for a specific time

Tags: c++, loops, time

I'm getting started with C++ and I decided to do some random coding just for practice. So I was thinking of making a simple benchmarking program, here's how far I have gotten:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "press any key to start benchmarking" << endl;
    cin.get();

    int pref_scorecounter = 0;
    time_t pref_timestart = time(0);
    do {
        pref_scorecounter++;
        time_t pref_timefinish = time(0);
        int pref_timeduration = pref_timefinish - pref_timestart;
    } while ( pref_timeduration < 5 );
    cout << "Score: " << pref_scorecounter;
    cin.get();
}
```

The way it works is that it shows how much times has the loop happened in 5 seconds. But I get this error:

```
error: 'pref_timeduration' was not declared in this scope
```

Any ideas why the variable defined in a loop doesn't work? Also why does this program not run at 100% cpu?

This project was ported from a PHP project I made a while ago and that PHP code works 100%, I tested with different servers and etc.

```
<?php
$pref_scorecounter = 0;
$pref_timestart = microtime(true); 
do {
    $pref_scorecounter++;
    $pref_timefinish = microtime(true);
    $pref_timeduration = $pref_timefinish - $pref_timestart;
} while($pref_timeduration < 5);
echo "Score: " . $pref_scorecounter;
?>
```

I can add some complex calculations later though...

Comment: The issue itself is not related to php.

Comment: It was added into a PHP category automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pref_timeduration` is defined within the scope block of the `while` loop.

It therefore cannot be used in the loop exit test: `while( pref_timeduration < 5)` is invalid and your compiler is telling you this.

One fix is to declare `pref_timeduration` just before the `do`. You can put an extra pair of braces around the whole thing if you're concerned about leaking the scope of `pref_timeduration` to other parts of the function.

Answer (score 1):

The languages have different scoping rules.

In C++ the scope ends on closing bracket. If you want to use the variable in the condition, its definition has to be outside of loop scope.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simple, it is related to the scope of the variable `pref_timeduration`. You've declared the variable inside the loop while you're trying to access it outside. Initialize the variable outside the `do {} while()` loop and update it inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In a do-while statement, the body is executed before the condition is evaluated. But for what's in the body to work properly, including the declaration of pref_timeduration, the condition must be true. Bjarne Stroustrup recommends against the use of do-while loops.